# Example of using preparser of google v8

Tags: javascript, v8

I need to parse JavaScript code and get to AST elements tree. I'm trying to use Google V8 JavaScript engine. Did anyone tried Google V8 preparser? Any examples of code? Or references to open-source projects which employed Google V8 preparser? Also does nayone have experience suing pre-parsed data to achieve AST from it?

Answer (score 5):

V8's preparser is not intended to be used as a standalone parser, it does not even build full AST. Preparser is a part of V8's internal lazy parsing/compilation infrastructure, that exists to speed up initial parsing of large JavaScript files. It can only be used in conjunction with an an actual parser inside V8.